# Updated Python Gurus: Find the difference between these two running sum functions(do they do the same thing?) Hackerrank: Array Manipulation

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, max

On Hackerrank, I was solving the Array Manipulation question and when I submitted my code with runningSum_A my code passed all the test cases. But when I submitted runningSum_B, it failed many test cases. Can someone please explain the logic behind this? Is there something inherently different between these two functions, because they seem the same to me? (Link to the question: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=arrays)

```
def runningSum_A(arr):
    maxSum = -math.inf
    runningSum = 0
    for i in arr:
        runningSum += i
        maxSum = max(maxSum, runningSum)
    return maxSum

def runningSum_B(arr):
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        arr[i] += arr[i - 1]
    return max(arr)

def arrayManipulation(n, queries):
    arr = [0]*(n+2)
    for query in queries:
        arr[query[0]] += query[2]
        arr[query[1]+1] -= query[2]

    ############################################################
    #call runningSum_A or runningSum_B function here
```

Comment: Could you describe the question itself first?

Comment: Hi Daniel. I have provided a link to the question. Basically, the question is a list of list is provided and that list provides the index and value that  we are supposed to add to another list. Then we provide the max value in that array. Sorry if this sounds confusing. I think the link to the question can describe it better than I can.

Comment: Yes, that is what you are ultimately trying to achieve. But what are you asking us? Do you just want us to solve the whole problem for you?

Comment: No, I have already solved the question on Hackerrank. I came up with two solutions to find the running sum in the problem. One sets a variable that adds each element in the array and another that sums the current array with previous array and replace the current element in the array. The 1st solution works, but the 2nd doesnt. They follow the same logic and when coded in Java it works. Is there something inherently different between these two implementations in python that I am unaware and is causing the test cases in my second implementation in Hackerrank to fail.